# Dog rubbing nose on bed and tapping bone. Any explanation?

Tags: dogs, behavior

Below I link to a video of my dog rubbing its nose on its bed repeatedly and then tapping a bone with its nose. Then the whole cycle was repeated. She did this for about 15 minutes. Can anyone explain it?

https://youtu.be/iCrFxdHAHd8

Answer (score 3):

Instinct tells her it'd be best to bury this bone for later use. Naturally, dogs are using their claws for digging into the ground and their nose for covering up again. It is like pushing sand onto something so it is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

One of our two Huskies does the exact same thing, but only when he wants to move something or - which I think is the actual reason here as well - **when he wants to dig in something like food for later**.

The pillow is soft, so by instinct the dog might assume it can be moved over the bone.